# Windows 7 run batch file at low priority in wide window

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, process

I have a long-running, CPU-intensive job that I want to run with low priority. This is easily done in a Windows 7 batch file with START /LOW.

The only problem is that it starts a separate window which is the default width for a command window, which is very narrow, less than half the width of one monitor, which makes it harder to read the results than I would like. (I have set the properties of the command window shortcut so that it normally starts a wider window, but that isn't getting applied in this context.)

How can I cause the long-running job to run in a wide command window? I have tried START /LOW /B to run the low priority job within the current window, but that leaves the process associated with the job still hanging around even after the job finishes, which messes things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best ways to do it

As you said " default width for a command window, which is very narrow "

This is because you did not change default width and height of command prompt. you must have to change default width and height of command prompt it self not for the shortcut.

```
 open run and type cmd, hit enter
 right click on title bar and chose properties
 go to layout menu and change window size to desire (optimal width:200 Height:50)
 from font menu change fonts also to desire size
 press ok and exit CMD
```

**(You must run CMD again and drag CMD to desire position on screen and close it.which position you will close it, CMD will run always on exact position with same windows and font size you set.**

Now when ever you will run batch file or command prompt they will always run in same position, same windows size and font.

Note : this solution can do trick on windows 7 as well as windows 10.

Extra : there is quick and dirty solution for this also, add this line in Batch file 
after @echo

```
 MODE CON COLS=999 LINES=999
```

but this will only increase size of window, nothing will change with fonts etc.